# Free CSS UI Templates

Tags: css, templates, user-interface, frameworks

Could someone show me some css ui framework/template for consistent web application, something like:

- http://www.webguitemplates.com/templates/futurism/futurism-blue
- http://www.webguitemplates.com/templates/simplus/simplus-silver
- http://www.adminizio.com/
- http://gooeytemplates.myshopify.com/products/blue-atom
- http://gooeytemplates.myshopify.com/products/blue-carbon
- http://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/admin-skins
- http://demo.sproutcore.com/sample_controls/
- http://ukijs.org/functional/wave.html

The framework/template is "pure" css and not javascript/ajax framework (ExtJS, JQuery UI, YUI, etc) and can work without JQuery or other JS/Ajax framework (mainly it just the UI).

Maybe be a bit too much, but consider the template included:

- Form styling (input, button, select, fieldset, radio, checkbox, etc)
- Table styling (header, row-highlight, row-focus, etc)
- Navigation styling (tab based, list based, etc)
- Text typography (h1...h3, b, i, u, em, strong, a, etc)

I found some here:
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/free-admin-template-for-web-applications/
http://blogfreakz.com/web-design/excellent-free-admin-template-for-web-applications/

I hope i could find any, especially the one that looks like google product (gmail, wave, analytics), just for speeding up web design process while maintaining consistency on UI design.

Comment: Am I missing what this has to do with programming? Voting to close.

Comment: You should try asking at http://doctype.com/

Comment: CSS questions are considered okay, and questions about frameworks for other languages are okay, so I'd vote to keep it open if it stays related to helping web developers develop good-looking applications faster based on a base UI library.  (Not if he's just looking for free HTML/CSS templates)

Comment: i just hoping we could find some nice and consistent UI framework for developing web application based on "pure" css

Comment: Why restrict yourself to 'pure' css? If you're not using jQuery are you just not using javascript? Is jQuery really so bad?

Comment: I think his point is that the look and feel of the web app shouldn't be dependent upon the JS library behind it.  It's just CSS and images.

Comment: @philfreo: correct, that what i was talking about

Comment: If you want to keep the question at least change the title to capitalize correctly... As for **UI** , do keep in mind that there will certainly be things that cannot be accomplished with today's set of `input` and form elements, and that browsers are fairly restrictive on how you can style them with CSS.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend without any hesitation http://themeforest.net/ , or any other envato web site

Answer (score 2):

http://www.adminizio.com/

There's awesome free version ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of free UI frameworks—I'd recommend http://www.blueprintcss.org/. If you need the design, you're probably going to have to pay. $10 - $50 is a small price to pay for a really good ui.

Answer (score 1):

I´d recommend AdminSquare – http://www.adminsquare.com, the price is $50, but they provide unlimited licence for using and all feature updates for free.

Answer (score 0):

## Followings two are the best UI framework I have ever seen

- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) (has almost everything but old browser won't support many things)
- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) (well cross-browser support and actively maintained)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Karmanta Lite – Free [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com) Admin Template**

**Karmanta – [Free Bootstrap Admin Template](http://dmartify.com/downloads/karmanta-lite-free-bootstrap-admin-template/)** is the excellent responsive and multipurpose Admin Theme powered with Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 Framework. Karmanta can be used for any type of web applications dashboard: custom admin panels, admin dashboards, CMS, CRM, SAAS and websites: CMSs, SAAS, CRM, HRMS, Support & Social portal, e-commerce, personal business, corporate. Karmanta has a minimal, sleek, clean and intuitive design which makes your next project look awesome and yet user friendly.